# Would a Response.Redirect() loop cause IIS service to die?

Tags: iis-6, redirect

If classic asp got into a redirect loop, would it be enough to kill the IIS service.
Or does the act of redirecting not consume that many resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a setting in most browsers that restricts the number of redirects. I believe IE is 7, FireFox is something silly like 20.

I don't entirely agree with Joe.  Whilst the act of an unending loop is generally bad, and will eat up resources, your redirect loop involves a connection to a web server, which will clear up once the redirect message is sent to the client.  The IIS instance isn't really looping, it's telling your browser to go do something, and it will (should) cleanup after itself.

That being said, if your page does something server intensive, queries databases, holds open other connections, does a bunch of other stuff, then it will cause some issues, but IIS is pretty resilient, and will usually start rejecting connections before crashing. Throw a whole bunch of requests at that page that loops, and you may be looking at memory issues, but entirely depends on what is going on in the script.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that if it is in fact a loop that eventually it would cause IIS to crash. A loop has no end, therefore regardless of how little resources each iteration of the loop consumes, eventually all of the resources would be exhausted and IIS would crash.

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty - A very good point, would IIS try to restart itself by default? Or would it stay in the stopped state? Would you get a warning in IIS manager?